# Animation sequence

Tags: animation

So I have a mixamo character with soccer animations. So lets assume a player is running, kicks the ball (ball lands in the net) and then he runs of celebrating.

The player himself has 3 different animations. How do I make these animations go in sequence? Right now the player keeps going back to his starting position as oppose to a flow of these actions.

Comment: Hey, could you show what you have at the moment?  Not sure at what step you are at.  Do you already have the animations placed as strips on the timeline?

Comment: You probably want to use the NLA editor. Each animation will be considered as a unit and you can combine those units.

Comment: is the running animation a cyclic 1 position animation?